# Trying to check if value is in sqlite3 with Python

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, cs50

I am trying to check if a value is in SQLite with python to then either update the table if the value exists or create a new value if it is not.  I have tried to create a cursor to check rows, append the rows to a list with loop, check if value exists, check the count of the rows... I seems to get hung up on the if statement when trying to access the value initialized from the query.  Here is the code:

```
checkT = db.execute("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM trans WHERE stock=:stock AND id=:user_id", stock=request.form.get("symbol"), user_id=session["user_id"])
if checkT > 0:
            print("there")
else:
            print("not there")
```

How can I fix this? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [CS50 Library for Python doc for execute](https://cs50.readthedocs.io/libraries/cs50/python/#cs50.SQL.execute)

> **Returns**
>
> for SELECTs, a `list` of `dict` objects, each of which represents a row in the result set; for INSERTs, the primary key of a newly inserted row (or None if none); for UPDATEs, the number of rows updated; for DELETEs, the number of rows deleted; for CREATEs, True on success; on error, a RuntimeError is raised

`checkT` is a `list` with one element, which is a `dict` with one key/value pair.

This `checkT[0]['COUNT(*)']` will give the number returned from the sql. Counting the rows would not be appropriate in this case because this query will always return one row.

One hint: column names in a SELECT can be aliased, given a different name, like so:

`SELECT COUNT(*) as  count from......`. It would just be typing convenience, because then the key in the returned dict will be `count` instead of `COUNT(*)`.

Remember: in the `flask run` terminal there is a traceback with gives more details information on the error received (assuming "hung up" means a 500 Internal Server Error).

Comment: AWESOME, thank you!  I have gotten it to work with your help!  I appreciate you taking the time to explain it.